# WordPress redirection gives 404 after moving site from a server to another

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, debian

After migrating my WordPress sites from my old hosting provider to my new VPS thought my sites works fine but it was giving 404 not found everywhere
it's a redirection issue because the home page is working fine.

My rewrite mod is activated, the `.htaccess` is the default WordPress one,
for migrating the site I proceed like this:

1. I copy the old files in the right vhost folder
2. I create a mysql username and database  for the new server
3. I update the wp-config.php file with the new params.
4. I import the old database to the new empty database

I copied this from WordPress official documentation and it worked fine for other sites but now it's not working.

Tried to google the issue but I haven't got the solution.

This is my `.htaccess` file (standard wordpress):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you refreshed your permalinks?  Under Settings .. Permalinks?  Sometimes they need to be flushed

Comment: i did @Hobo but only the defaut form of permalinks works and all the  other forms havn't worked for me i also activated  **AllowOverride** like recommanded here [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-everywhere-after-moving-to-new-server)  ,nothing happened too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is so simple but can be caused by  various factors

1) You must check if your apache **mod_rewrite** is enabled

2) Check if **Allowoverride** is set to **All**

3) Check if you have a .htaccess file

4) Check if Wordpress have the right to write on it (chmod 666 .htaccess)

for %postname% permalink check if you have a similar .htaccess to this one :

```
#Begin Wordpress 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>   

# END WordPress
```

For my case i forgot to set **Allowoverride** in a correct way